# Error connecting mysql to Android app using php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, php-parser

I have a php script that connects android app with mysql DB but when I run it I have errors which I cannot not figure out.

config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'andro_test');?>
```

php script

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$name = clean($_POST['name']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$cpassword = clean($_POST['cpassword']);

//Input Validations
if($name == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($cpassword == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Confirm password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $cpassword) != 0 ) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Passwords do not match';
    $errflag = true;
}

//Check for duplicate login ID
if($login != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE name='$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                // here I want to show a msg that auto disappear...
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'username  already in use';    
            $_SESSION['errmsg'] = 'username  already in use';
            unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);

            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: D:\Third Year\FYP\dawah\arabteam\src\andro\website");// here I need my php to direct the user to my next android file ".java" under the app. file in my PC
    exit();
}

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO test(name, password) VALUES('$name','".md5($_POST['password'])."')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
                // here I want to show a msg that auto disappear...
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'succefull registeration';
                    $_SESSION['errmsg'] = 'succefull registeration';
                    unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);


            $errflag = true;
}else {
    echo("registeration failed");
}?>
```

my android app files

my main java file

```
package andro.website;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ComminicateWithWebsiteActivity extends Activity 
{
TextView txtUserName;
TextView txtPassword;
TextView confpass;
Button btnReg;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents()
{
    txtUserName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtPassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    confpass= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);
    btnReg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    btnReg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                String usName=txtUserName.getText().toString();
                String pass=txtPassword.getText().toString();
                String url="http://10.0.2.2/register-exec.php?name="+usName+"&password="+pass;
                Server server=new Server(url, getApplicationContext());
                server.run();
            }
            catch(Exception c)
            {
                Log.e("Thread Exception", c.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

server file

```
package andro.website;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Server
{
String url;
Context context;

public Server(String url,Context context)
{
    this.url=url;
    this.context=context;
}

public void run()
{
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.d("request", "done");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            Log.d("respone", "done");
            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            Log.d("Buffer", "readed");
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Toast", line);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception c)
        {
            Log.e("Exception",c.getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

my mainifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_width="178dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnReg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="reg" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/confirmpassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

the error I got deoesn't appear in my logcat rather it appears in the android VM screen

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not mention what is the error exactly, but it is probably `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you execute

```
Server server=new Server(url, getApplicationContext());
server.run();
```

You should consider yousing `AsynchTask` ([see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)) for your network operations

A quick fix for your code is to let your `Server` class extends `Thread` and call `server.start()` instead of `server.run()`

**Edit:**

Also if there is not valid reason to use `ApplicationContext`, you should use your activity context, e.g.

```
Server server=new Server(url, this);
```

if you want to use `Toast` from the server class, you have to run it in the `UI thread` by calling `Activity.runOnUiThread`

Comment: Just extending Thread won't work, since Toast can't be used from another thread. Using AsyncTask is the simplest solution.

Comment: I already recommended using `AsyncTask`; however it *does* involve more work that just modifying the code to use thread (even with neccessary changes to use `Toast`), so it is *not* the simplest.

Comment: sorry guys for my late response the error I got appears on my android app. on the AVDM it's a two pop-up msg  I upload them here http://i46.tinypic.com/jskt3n.png             and this is the 2nd msg http://i46.tinypic.com/35nbvy0.png